# Wet Vent in Basement Bathroom

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

Finishing a bathroom downstairs where the rough waste lines already exist. I live in Michigan, my question is around venting. I have seen AAV's under sinks in this state before, but it looks like there is already a vent on the sink line. When I put in the waste line for the sink do I need to extend the vent stack higher and put the AAV higher in the wall, or do I put an AAV under the sink after the P trap? Not sure I have seen multiple AAV's on the same tree before.

[image]

Comment: If there's a vent line for the sink, why not tie all the other vents into that stack? Or are you saying that there's already an AAV under the sink and you want to tie into that, or something else entirely?

Comment: No finished waste plumbing currently exists. just stub outs, not sure if I can use existing AAV or if that was just put in during stub outs until finish work was completed. I recall back in the day when I did plumbing (15 years ago) that AAV vents need to be within 42 inches of the P trap, but maybe I'm misremembering.